# Take a Current Git Branch and "reset" Its contents to Master

Tags: git

At work, each developer has his own development branch we work off of, ie. branch = dev_name_of_employee. IE. dev_jon

dev_jon has a new feature with over 100 commits in it that is not ready to be tested or deployed, so I created another branch to put that new feature in called staging_jon (could have called it holding_jon, whatever).

Now I need to start on another feature and have dev_jon contain the contents of master. Kind of a revert back to master thing.

How can I do this without deleting dev_jon and its remote branch, then recreating it from master? I cant stage all these changes because they are already pushed.

Or is there just a better way to have each employee work on his/her own consistant branch during development?

Comment: Don't give the developers personal branches, but use branches per feature. That way, developers can share branches without having to ask "your branch or mine".

Comment: From the experience I have gained since posting this, branching via developer name is a poor idea. It is much better to branch by a prefixed with a type, then a ticket id referenced to a ticket management system and suffixed with a short descriptions like: `bug/3452-table-search-broken` or `feature/89756-add-the-things`.

Comment: Fortunately, I can see you were able to find the right way to work on your branches.What should be the idea of branching per developer? I wonder if this will be the most efficient way to work on that project in the future. Also, be careful when hard resetting your branch if your approach changes to a `feature` based git flow and then there is more than one developer working on it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In dev_jon, you can do:

```
git reset --hard master
```

May not be directly applicable / relevant, but you can look at GitHub flow: http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Comment: GitHub Flow suggests to NOT keeping a consistant branch_name, ie dev_jon for each developer, but create a new branch for each new feature. Thats probably how it should be. Ill try `git reset --hard master` and see if that does what I want it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think your current model is really ideal, a developer should be able to develop on multiple features at the same time therefore only one branch per developer is not the most flexible. Anyway in your situation here what I would do assuming that dev_jon is tracking origin/master:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This is also assuming you are currently on dev_jon branch.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yeah I dont think is ideal either.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a hard reset to get your `dev-jon` branch to be the same as master, but you'll have to be careful when you come to publish your new work. The remote branch `origin\dev_jon` will be your old feature and when you come to push you'll get a warning like the following

```
 ! [rejected]        dev_jon -> dev_jon (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/tmp/example'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Consider creating a feature branch as suggested by larsmans.

Comment: In that case, if you need to publish the change, `git push --force-with-lease` is your friend.